# How check if variable contains substring in c shell?

Tags: csh

I am trying to check if a variable contains a specific substring. The test value is `"test_tpTest171_ess"`

```
 if ($test =~ "Test171") then
    echo "statement is working"
```

Also tried:

```
 $test == "*Test171*"
 $test == *Test171*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you *Also tried* would have worked if you had used the correct operator.

The *glob-pattern* on the right hand side of `=~` must match the whole left hand operand, so if you want to allow extra text before and after `Test171`, you have to add `*` there:

```
if ($test =~ *Test171*) echo "statement is working"
```